# Ending a program

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I end my program if something is true?

This is my code

```
  count=0

  num=input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? ")
  while (num>'0' and num<'5'):
      while num=='1':
        Do something
      while num=='2':
        Do something
      While num=='3':
        Do something
      while num=='4' and count!=1:

         print("The End")
         count= count+1
```

I want the program to end while num is '4'

Comment: Use an `if` rather than a `while` I think?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I want the program to end while num is '4'"? Please try to describe the end condition in other words. It seems that we have problems to understand you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all use integers not strings:

```
>>> '100' > '5'
False
```

And use `if` instead of `while`, if any of the conditions is True then you can use the `break` statement to break out of the loop.

```
count = 0
num = int(input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? "))
while 0 < num < 5:
    if num == 1:
       Do something
       ...
    if num == 4 and count != 1:
       print("The End")
       count += 1
       break          #breaks out of the `while` loop
```

Also note that you should use `if-elif-else` conditions here instead of just `if`'s, because here all `if` conditions are going to be checked, but with `if-elif-else` conditions will short-circuit(jump to the end of if-elif-else block) as soon as one of the condition is `True`.

Comment: thanks for that, but is it possible to break out of the while loop without using break in this case?

Comment: @user2775042 You can set `num` to a value that dissatisfies `0 < num < 5` condition, and the `while` loop will automatically break in the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if num=='4' and count!=1:
```

not

```
while num=='4' and count!=1:
```

Comment: i get the same result when i use if

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` in place of `while loop` like,

```
while (num>0 and num<5):
  if num==1:
    Do something
  if num==2:
    Do something
  if num==3:
    Do something
  if num==4 and count!=1:
     print("The End")
     count= count+1
     break
```

Comment: i am still getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

Add a `break` statement and use numbers

```
while (num > 0 and num < 5):
    while num == 1:
        #Do something
    while num == 2:
        #Do something
    while num == 3:
        #Do something
    if num == 4 and count != 1:
        print ("The End"); count += 1
        break
```